# Is it more efficient for severs to send an image file or a path to an image file to the client?

Tags: node.js, express, server

I'm using express js to serve files to an angular app and I'm deciding between these approaches:

`res.status(201).json({ imagepath: '<URL>' });`

`res.sendFile('<URL>');`

I'm thinking that sending the url will force an extra round trip so I should go with the sendFile but I want to doublecheck. Is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: If you just want to send the image file, you should just send the binary. But the other thing you have to make sure you do is set the `Content-type` header so that the receiver knows what kind of image/file this is

Comment: Either will work just fine.  If there's a reason that this image file needs to be requested directly by URL so you already have a route for serving this image file, then it's simplest to just send that URL or redirect to that URL rather than serving the image two different ways and keep your server logic simpler.

Answer (score 0):

The best option would be to store the image file on something like AWS S3 and then send the file URL using your Express application. You would use the `aws-sdk` package [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-sdk) to save the image to S3 (detailed article [here](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-set-up-simple-image-upload-with-node-and-aws-s3-84e609248792/)). Then you would send the URL location of that image to your database to be stored.